# how to print array to csv in standalone script

Tags: magento-1.9, php

hi am trying to put my array data to csv in magento 1.9 where i fetching all the order details using standalone script

**my php script**

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();


foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
        $orders['orders'][] = array(
            'id'            => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'store'         => 'magento',
            'status'        => $order->getStatus(),
            'name'          => $order->getCustomerName(),
            'email'         => $order->getCustomerEmail(),
            'telephone'     => $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone(),
            'street'        => $order->getShippingAddress()->getStreet(),
            'pincode'       => $order->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode(),
            'city'          => $order->getShippingAddress()->getCity(),
            'weight'        => $order->getWeight(),


        );    

     foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
       $orders['orders']['items'][] = array(
            'id'            => $order->getIncrementId(),
            'name'          => $item->getName(),
            'sku'           => $item->getSku(),
            'Price'         => $item->getPrice(),
            'Ordered Qty'   => $item->getQtyOrdered(),


        );

       $fp = fopen('test_export.csv', 'w');

foreach ($orders as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);

    }
    }
print_r($orders); 


echo "<pre>"; print_r($orders);
```

**output:-**

```
Array ( [orders] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 100000001 [store] => magento [status] => complete [name] => pramod mishra [email] => pramod.mishra@netsmartz.net [telephone] => 01234567890 [street] => Array ( [0] => plot no-10 ) [pincode] => 160101 [city] => chandigarh [weight] => 10.0000 ) [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 100000001 [name] => test [sku] => test [Price] => 10.0000 [Ordered Qty] => 1.0000 ) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way:

```
$file = Mage::getBaseDir('media'). DS .'file.csv';
$csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$csv->setLineLength(20480);
$csv->saveData($file, $csvdata);
```

**$csvdata** should be mutli arary. Ex.

```
$csvdata = [
    [
        'a',
        'b'
    ],
    [
        'c',
        'd'
    ]
]
```

***[Update]***

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection $orderCollection */
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$orders = [];
$orders[] = [
    'ID',
    'Store',
    'Status',
    'Name',
    'Email',
    'Telephone',
    'Street',
    'Pincode',
    'City',
    'Weight',
    'Products'
];

/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order */
foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
    $orderInfo = [
        $order->getIncrementId(),
        'magento',
        $order->getStatus(),
        $order->getCustomerName(),
        $order->getCustomerEmail()
    ];

    if ($order->getIsVirtual()) {
        $orderInfo[] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
        $orderInfo[] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet();
        $orderInfo[] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode();
        $orderInfo[] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode();
    } else {
        $orderInfo[] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone();
        $orderInfo[] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getStreet();
        $orderInfo[] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
        $orderInfo[] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
    }

    $orderInfo[] = $order->getWeight();
    $itemsStr = [];
    $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $item */
    foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
        $orderItem = [
            $order->getIncrementId(),
            $item->getName(),
            $item->getSku(),
            $item->getPrice(),
            $item->getQtyOrdered()
        ];

        $itemsStr[] = implode('|', $orderItem);
    }

    $orderInfo[] = implode("\n", $itemsStr);
    $orders[] = $orderInfo;
}

$file = Mage::getBaseDir('media'). DS .'order.csv';
$csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$csv->setLineLength(20480);
$csv->saveData($file, $orders);
```

Comment: can you please be more precise with your ans its really confusing

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: na its not working,moreover its not even generating csv

Comment: Did you run this my updated answer? I have checked M1.9.4.1 + php7.3.

Comment: yes wait i will post my ans on how i achieved this take a look

Answer (score 0):

this is just for help this is how i acheived this

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection $orderCollection */
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$orders = [];
$orders[] = [
    'ID',
    'Store',
    'Status',
    'Name',
    'Email',
    'Telephone',
    // 'Street',
    'Pincode',
    'City',
    'Weight',
    'Products'
];

/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order */
foreach ($orderCollection as $order) {
    $orderInfo = [
        $order->getIncrementId(),
        'magento',
        $order->getStatus(),
        $order->getCustomerName(),
        $order->getCustomerEmail()
    ];

    if ($order->getIsVirtual()) {
        $orderInfo[] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
        // $orderInfo[] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet();
        $orderInfo[] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode();
        $orderInfo[] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode();
    } else {
        $orderInfo[] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone();
        // $orderInfo[] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getStreet();
        $orderInfo[] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
        $orderInfo[] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
    }

    $orderInfo[] = $order->getWeight();
    $itemsStr = [];
    $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
    /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $item */
    foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
        $orderItem = [
            $order->getIncrementId(),
            $item->getName(),
            $item->getSku(),
            $item->getPrice(),
            $item->getQtyOrdered()
        ];

        $itemsStr[] = implode('|', $orderItem);
    }

    $orderInfo[] = implode("\n", $itemsStr);
    $orders[] = $orderInfo;


$fp = fopen('order_export.csv', 'w');

foreach ($orders as $val) {
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}

fclose($fp);


}


print_r($orders);
```

Comment: This is not good approch